# How do I input an incremented value into selected column in Oracle SQL and/or PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am in the process of updating a huge DB and can not for the life of me figure this out.

```
SELECT rank_column FROM schema.table
WHERE id IN (x,y,z,a,b,c) AND lll AND ooo
```

I'm a little stuck here since I need to set rank_*column for x to be updated to 1A, rank*_column for y to be 2A, z to be 3A, etc.

There are only 30 or so values here so I can do them by hand, but on the more difficult note, I also need to need to rank the values NOT in this list and we're talking about somewhere near 300,000+.  The order for these should not matter, but how do I set the first read row to 1Z, the second to 2Z, the third to 3Z, etc? Thank you for any help it would be much appreciated!

I attempted to use pl/sql but every single time, it updates with the very same number so I might have 1B for all when I want 1B,2B,3B etc. I need something like this down below except I need to iterate each for each row. I attempted to put iterate:=iterate+1 inside of the set statement so everytime it sets rank it will iterate that rank, but I keep returning "missing equal sign" on the set line right over the equal sign.

```
DECLARE
  iterate number:=1;
BEGIN
  UPDATE schema.table
     SET rank = iterate||'A'**,ITERATE = ITERATE + 1**
   WHERE ID IN (11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,777777,88888,99999)
     AND type = '01'
     AND manufacturer = '000111'
     AND indicator = '0';
  iterate:= iterate +1;
END;
```

Comment: I think you only need this `UPDATE tab SET rank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 0)  WHERE ...`

Comment: Thank you, that should help if I need a defined order (I'm still not sure if I do but thats a long story), thank your time!

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I think that might give *ORA-30483: window functions are not allowed here*

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
update tab_lvl set rank=rownum||'A' where id in (30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100);
    
8 rows updated.
    
select id,rank from tab_lvl where id in (30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100);


        ID RANK
---------- ---------------
        30 1A
        40 2A
        50 3A
        60 4A
        70 5A
        80 6A
        90 7A
       100 8A

8 rows selected.
```

Comment: Actually, yes. I cant believe I didn't think rownum would work for this, it never crossed my mind. I might need to add another AND clause to stop it from updating ranks that were set in previous years for my NOT IN condition. Thanks for the help!